# Only people who have paid can sign-up for application...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, saas, billing

I built an authentication system for my app following these Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch and http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

People are not going to be able to use the app if they don't have an account. It's finally working fine and dandy, just the way I want it to.

Now I'm wondering how exactly to go about restricting sign-ups only to people who have paid. To be honest I'm pretty clueless about the billing aspect of things.

The most basic solution is to use Paypal, and redirect users to the sign-up page after they've paid. I would actually prefer to use Paypal, and don't mind if they have to go outside the site to put in payment details.

But that method has a huge hole: customers could decide to cancel their Paypal subscription and just sign up for an account using the raw signup page. Or even worse, share it with everyone.

I know about [RailsKit for SaaS](http://railskits.com/saas/) but the price is a little scary (not to mention having to pay $1,000 if I want to use it on multiple sites) so I'd much rather go for an opensource/lower-cost solution if possible.

Comment: how many users are we talking about here? is it possible for you to manually "approve" users based on whether you get a paypal notification from them?

Comment: @antony-scott I'd be really ecstatic if I could get 200 people paying monthly. Manually "approving" is my absolute last resort, as people would want to get their accounts and right away.

Comment: if you do find your answer please post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. That way others with the same problem will benefit by searching stackoverflow in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing -- after watching the 24 minute (!) video, Ryan Bates comes to the rescue once again. The "subscription" table can easily be a "users" table with authentication. I'll spend the next couple of days trying to implement this. It's only for Pro users, but if you have this problem I think it's worth spending the $9 to get your hands on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get notification when user paid through paypal. Save it and then set a flag in session.

So when user submit the signup form, make sure the flag in session exists and what's more, make sure the account info such as email has already paid.

Another choice is that opening signup form but only allow the paid accounts use the app by adding a before_filter.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past year or two there have been several new payment solutions launch that may be perfect for you.

For one of my sites I use http://www.chargify.com who will sit in-between your site and payment gateway. Althrough there is an extra cost with having this additional service you will benefit from their great support team and all the additional features that they have, e.g. statements, coupons, dealing with expired cards etc...

There are a few other companies doing similar things to chargify such as reccurly.com saasy.com etc...

If you are after a base application that integrates with these services (a bit like RailsKit), check out chargify's consultant page http://chargify.com/consultants/ where a few people have provided solutions.

Just something else for you to consider.

Comment: Hey Scott, I'm actually aware of Chargify and all the other solutions (Saasy, Reccurly, CheddarGetter, etc.) and to be honest I would love to use them. But I don't know if it's possible to integrate them with a sign-up form that I have within Rails? If so, would there be any resources you could point me to that I could read up on? It'd be cool if they could handle stuff like account cancellations automatically so I don't have to deactivate accounts myself.

Comment: Hi, With chargify,  I actually have my own signup form and then once a user has completed that successfully, I then send them off to chargify's hosted payment form http://docs.chargify.com/hosted-page-integration . When the user has completed this form they retrun them back to my application. The return page they hit makes a simple api request to chargify to check that the signup was successful.

Comment: Here's an example chargify postback controller too (tells your app when ever something has happened in chargify) https://gist.github.com/601151 Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look. Anything helps.